# PHP Get value from a button without submitting

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a long form. On one part the user has to choose between different options before introducing some information and then create the account.

I tried doing something like

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="0" name="button">
  <input type="button" value="1" name="button">
  <input type="button" value="2" name="button">
</form>

<button>Create account</button>

<?php 

if(!empty['button']){
  $btn_val = $_POST['button'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO table btn_value VALUES :value";

  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)

  $stmt->bindParam(':value', $btn_val);

  $stmt->execute();
}

?>
```

but when I try submitting it PHP doesn't retrieve those values. I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17186513/13949993) with Javascript but it doesn't work. Some other answers which work is to use a radio but that will affect the frontend since I need to display a button.

Comment: `type="button"` doesn't submit the form, that would be `type="submit"`

Comment: yes, because I don't want it to submit, just to hold a value which can be selected by the user

Comment: `if(!empty['button'])` should most likely be `if(!empty($_GET['button']))`

Comment: You can't get form values in PHP without submitting the form/using javascript

Comment: It is going to be submitted at some point but from what I saw the easiest way to get value from a button is to use <input type="submit">. Which I don't want. It is submitting, but not at this stage of the form

Comment: Ah, I guess I got it now. Use radio's, style them to look like buttons. Or use javascript to fill a hidden input with the value of the button that has been clicked

Comment: I've tried with the hidden input with JS, as I mentioned above. But it didn't work.

Comment: I think I will use radio as you mentioned. Can't find an alternative, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to submit information to a database without actually submitting the file is with asynchronous javascript.

to grab the information with the click of a button, you need to create an onclick event on the button which will trigger a function to grab the information you want to send. After that, you will open a connection to php to send the information to the database.

Since PHP only works when the page is being loaded, you need to send the information to a different PHP script to actually send the data to the database.

Look into XMLHttpRequest

Eventually, you will get something like:

```
xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

create AJAX object

```
xml.open("POST",'yourphpscript.php',true)
```

set up connection to php script with the post method, and boolean value for asynchronous

```
xml.send();
```

send request.

for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: I don't want to submit it to the database, as I said in the comments. I mentioned that because apparently the only way to get the value from a button is to make it a <input type="submit">. The form will get submitted later, but it is not retrieving the value from the buttons

Comment: For php, it is impossible once the page is laoded. 
if it isnt connected to a database, you can skip the whole AJAX part, and ask for the information with javascript ( something in the line of an onclick event with event.target.value )

you wont be able to process it with php though.  Do you have a little bit more information on the actual use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to get the value of the clicked button and submit that in a hidden input field to server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="button" id="mybutton1" name="mybutton1" value="0">
        <input type="button" id="mybutton2" name="mybutton2" value="1"> 
        <input type="button" id="mybutton3" name="mybutton3" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" id="selectedButtonValue" value="" name="selectedButtonValue">
        <button>Create account</button>
    </form>
    <script>
         $("input").click(function()
         {
             var clickedButton=$(this).val();
             document.getElementById("selectedButtonValue").value=clickedButton;
         });
    </script>
             <?php
         if(isset($_POST["selectedButtonValue"]))
         {
             echo $_POST["selectedButtonValue"];
         }
         ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This can be done multiple ways.  Here I just used Jquery.